# Trouble using upstart to run simple node server

Tags: angularjs, node.js, server, upstart

I'm trying to run a simple node js server on digital ocean using this [tutorial](https://blog.gaya.ninja/articles/simple-node-js-web-server-digitalocean/) which I have successfully done before.  When I run `node server.js` my project loads on the ip perfectly, but after following the directions and using upstart, and running

`start node-server` I get

`node-server start/running, process 3265` but then nothing shows up at the ip address, and i get a `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` in the console.  What could I be doing wrong this time around?

I'm using a cross-origin `$.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers_mysql.php")`.  Could that be an issue?

When I `initctl status node-server` I get 
`node-server stop/waiting`

When I cd into `/usr/local/bin` I see nothing and `/usr/local/bin/node: not found` is in the logs.  In a working implementation I have a `npm` and `node` in the bin directory, but for some reason there isn't one in this project.  How do I create it?

Comment: Can you Post Full Error console  and update the relevant code ?

Comment: I dont see an error in the terminal console.  I see `node-server start/running, process 3265`,  and  I see just `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` in the chrome console and nothing more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting it work by copying the node and npm files from one droplet to another:

`scp -r /usr/local/bin/. root@0.0.0.0:/usr/local/bin`

Now i know that's pretty ghetto and probably not the right way, so i'm still holding out for the right answer.  Thank you.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-14-04